# Credit card Authorization using Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I have a website and a paypal merchant account.I need to authorize my customers credit card before doing a transaction.I hear about paypal's $1 card authorization.But i don't know customers ready to pay $1 for just verification.Is paypal refund them this amount? or any other better way for card authorization?

Thanks

Comment: this is not the place to ask this question... btw it credits the account so its not gone. just do a chargeback most paypal users do... grr

Comment: @Lawrence: can you suggest a better place than SO to ask for best practices on setting up and using a merchant account? :-)

Comment: reading the documentation is a good start....

Comment: Indeed, though I can't blame him for not being excited at the idea of reading the mess of documentation that is the PP API, lol. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the authorize/capture procedure with Paypal verification.

PP verification is a process whereby PP charges a small amount (under $1) to your CC with a special txid, which appears on your CC statement and requests that you confirm that txid (i.e. to prove you own it).

Authorize/Capture, by contrast, is a two-step payment process whereby you authorize (i.e. lock the funds) on the account in a first step (typically, to verify that the payment will succeed before proceeding in your workflow's follow-up steps), and capture (i.e. collect the funds) in a second step.

Comment: Thank you Denis for your reply,After $1 autherization, paypal refund the amount to the buyer?

Comment: No, it stays on your PP account.